# Laravel return relationship data based on locale

Tags: php, laravel

I have posts table that has related table where I store different translations based on `post_id` now when I want to return translation data based on user selected locale it says:

```
mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given
```

Here is my function

```
$posts = Post::with('translations', function($q) {
  $q->where('translate_code', app()->getLocale());
})->get();
dd($posts); // returning error above
```

But if I do this

```
$posts = Post::with('translations')->get();
dd($posts);
```

I will get following results

[image: one]

Here is translations data details:

[image: two]

**My question is:**

How can I return the one translation that has current locale name only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  using callback in with then use array of relations like below. Older version of laravel was working which you mentioned but latest version need array of relations when using callback.

```
$posts = Post::with(['translations'=> function($q) {
            $q->where('translate_code', app()->getLocale());
        }])->get();
```

Comment: Oops! I've completely forgot about array part :D thank you,

Answer (score 1):

using conditional [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models-on-morph-to-relationships) should be like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['translations'=> function($q) {
  $q->where('translate_code', app()->getLocale());
}])->get();
```

while the relation name is the key, a closer to get data should be the value for the associative array for 'with' statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can query your relation by using `whereHas()`.

Docs: [Laravel Docs Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

For example:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('translations', function ($query) {
   $query->where('translate_code', 'en');
})->get();
```

Maybe try to put the `app()->getLocale()` into a variable first. (after trying this out in tinker, this does seem te return a string, so may passing it by reference might help).

Comment: WhereHas doesn't return any relationship data with results

Comment: The problem is not `app()->getLocale()` the problem is that `translations` are array and it need to be string (only 1 row).

Comment: A relationship in Laravel always returns an array of the related models.